# Any bash magic to reference the previously typed parameter?

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

This question is a variant on a *previously asked* [How to repeat currently typed in parameter on bash console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/how-to-repeat-currently-typed-in-parameter-on-bash-console)

---

Many a time, I find myself wanting to slightly rename a file name in the shell, e.g.:

```
$ mv test_1.py _test_1.py
```

or

```
$ mv test_1.py test_1.py.org
```

I could use the suggestions in [How to repeat currently typed in parameter on bash console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/how-to-repeat-currently-typed-in-parameter-on-bash-console), but

### is there any *bash magic* that will allow me to just reference the previously typed parameter?

e.g., if the magic is `$M,` then - for the above - I'd use:

```
$ mv test_1.py _$M.py
$ mv test_1.py $M.org
```

Comment: You mean any magic not already covered in those answers?  I'm not grasping the way that this is a variant of that question (in particular [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165338/109842) seems like the closest to the "magic" you're looking for)

Comment: also [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40132/117549), like: `mv {,_}test_1.py`

Comment: Read `man bash`. Search `!!`

Comment: @Eric, thanks for pointing out the `!#$` answer, which I somehow missed, and which is what I was looking for. Sometimes it's right under your nose and you miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic works in two parts.

First, echo is aliased to e (echo will work also if you want no alias); second, we use "brace expansion":

```
$ e mv {,_}test_1.py              # Try to see if it works as expected.
mv test_1.py _test_1.py

          # If the arguments are what you want:

$ mv {,_}test_1.py                # Press ↑ (up arrow), remove `e`

$ !*                              # OR: Type `!*` --> last line after arg 0.
$ mv {,_}test_1.py                # If `histverify` is set.
```

The !* may be expanded with an space if you [enable magic-space](https://askubuntu.com/a/481270/615849) or if you [set `shopt -s histverify`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4086/190466) after you press enter, you will be given a chance to review the effect of the history expansion before pressing enter (again) to execute.

The other example:

```
$ e mv test_1.py{,.org}
mv test_1.py test_1.py.org        # The result of the brace expansion.
                                  # Review it, and if it is ok:
$ !*                              # type !* (use either space or enter)
                                  # That will depend on how you setup it.

$ mv test_1.py{,.org}        # The command appear again (enter to execute).
$
```

---

There is also the history expansion of `!#` which means the command line typed so far, and selecting the first command `:1`. If you have magic-space enabled, you type `mv test1.py !#:1` and press space, the command will change:

```
$ mv test_1.py !#:1                # Press space.
$ mv test_1.py test_1.py           # The command line change to this.
$ mv test_1.py test_1.org          # Edit and press enter to execute.
```