# Use reverse i search to cycle through only commands matching pattern

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, command-history, search

The contents of the command history file using `history | less` is:

```
555 ls
556 ls -a
557 echo "hello"
558 echo "hello again"
559 cd
560 pwd
561 echo "hello hello"
562 ls
563 echo "hello hello hello"
564 cd
565 pwd
```

I want to use reverse i search `` (reverse-i-search)`echo': `` to cycle through only commands in the command history file matching the pattern (i.e. in this case `echo') entered on the command line prompt, preferably until a specified line number in the command history file so that I only select previously used `echo` commands that I want to run again not all `echo` commands in the command history file

Using reverse i search finds the most recent usage of the command `echo` (hence the name reverse i search i.e. reverse searching for a command). However when scrolling forward in reverse order (i.e. reverse searching) bash scrolls through each line of the command history file starting from the line returned by the reverse i search, thus including commands I don't want to search for.

1. The reverse i search prompt `` (reverse-i-search)`echo': `` disappears once you start scrolling through the history list. How do you prevent the reverse i search prompt from disappearing during scrolling so that when you scroll forward in a reverse i search only the commands matching the pattern are shown?
2. If 1 is possible then how do you temporarily limit the reverse i search to a specific line number in the command history file in order to only select commands from a section of the command history file?

Note: a solution to this question would also be useful for those times when you have several instances of the same command line arguments and reverse i search does not find the one you're looking for

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @Philippos bash

Answer (score 0):

Once you have entered your search term, use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to search "up" for the previous command, and
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to switch direction and search "down" for the next one.

I have no idea how to limit the number of history entries to scan.

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> scrolls forward through lines in the history file containing the text pattern "echo" but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> freezes the terminal for me. It seems I need to put the command `stty -xion` in the start up script `~/.bashrc` to be able to step forward in matching command lines using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> without freezing the terminal [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12108/289865)[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4082). Perhaps you could update your post with this caveat and the workaround I mentioned

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: You can reverse the history file with tac and do normal search instead of reverse-i. history | tac | less

Comment: @elmo, you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use less command for history search, then a reverse search can more easily be done using tac command:

```
$ history | tac | less
```

This way you won't need to use reverse-i option in less.